# OSGi: missing requirement osgi.wiring.package with local bundle

Tags: osgi, cytoscape

My first time using maven and OSGi. I write app for Cytoscape, which uses OSGi. My app requires SMT solver. Firstly, I built regular JAR, using binding from: github.com/SRI-CSL/yices2_java_bindings. Then used bnd to create OSGi bundle with the following text (in .bnd file):

```
-classpath: yices.jar
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.sri.yices
ver: 1.0.0
-output: ${bsn}.jar
Bundle-Version: ${ver}
Export-Package: *; version=${ver}
```

MANIFEST.MF of SMT solver bundle:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1709709378499
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: com.sri.yices
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.sri.yices
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Created-By: 17.0.10 (Private Build)
Export-Package: com.sri.yices;version="1.0.0"
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(osgi.ee=UNKNOWN)"
Tool: Bnd-5.0.1.202101211358
```

My app's pom.xml contents about maven-bundle-plugin:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>${maven-bundle-plugin.version}</version>
 <extensions>true</extensions>
 <configuration>
  <instructions>
   <Bundle-SymbolicName>${bundle.symbolicName}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
   <Bundle-Name>BNwPAS</Bundle-Name>
   <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
   <Private-Package>${bundle.namespace}.*</Private-Package>
   <Export-Package>!${bundle.namespace}.*</Export-Package>
   <Bundle-Activator>${bundle.namespace}.CyActivator</Bundle-Activator>
  </instructions>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

pom.xml file contents about smt solver dependency:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.sri</groupId>
 <artifactId>yices</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.0</version>
 <scope>system</scope>
 <systemPath>${yices-systemPath}</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

MANIFEST.FM of project bundle:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1709972907550
Build-Jdk-Spec: 21
Bundle-Activator: org.veldalen.BNwPAS.internal.CyActivator
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: BNwPAS
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.veldalen.BNwPAS
Bundle-Version: 0.1
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin 5.1.9
Import-Package: com.sri.yices;version="[1.0,2)",java.lang,java.util,or
 g.cytoscape.model;version="[3.10,4)",org.cytoscape.service.util;versi
 on="[3.10,4)",org.cytoscape.work;version="[3.10,4)",org.osgi.framewor
 k;version="[1.8,2)"
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=17))"
Tool: Bnd-6.3.1.202206071316
```

When I try to start my app in Cytoscape, I get the following:
`Error starting bundle 127: Unable to resolve org.veldalen.BNwPAS [127](R 127.0): missing requirement [org.veldalen.BNwPAS [127](R 127.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.sri.yices)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[org.veldalen.BNwPAS [127](R 127.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.sri.yices)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]`
What am I missing?

I were expecting to have no wiring problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All third-party dependencies need to be embedded in the App jar file. (Cytoscape doesn't support multi-bundle apps, all dependencies not provided by the Cytoscape runtime have to be embedded in your App's jar file.)

Here is an example:
https://github.com/BaderLab/AutoAnnotateApp/blob/master/AutoAnnotate/pom.xml#L74-L89

Answer (score 1):

`Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(osgi.ee=UNKNOWN)"`

in the manifest indicates a problem with building the bundle. This will not resolve at runtime since it is UNKNOWN.

This bundle appears to have been created by a custom tool? `Created-By: 17.0.10 (Private Build)`.

Comment: I created bundle with bnd command line like so: bnd 'name'.bnd

Comment: update: I created the bundle more properly, so manifest looks like this: 'Created-By: 21.0.2 (Oracle Corporation)' and 'Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=17))"', but mentioned requirement is not resolved.

Comment: You also need to use a recent enough OSGi framework implementation that understands the version of Java you are using at runtime. This is needed so that the OSGi framework implementation can understand the Java runtime version matches the requested osgi.ee of Java 17.

Comment: I am using OSGi 8.0.0.

Comment: That is a specification not an implementation like Apache Felix or Eclipse Equinox.